# how to sync and delete the entries in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello all I am facing a problem in making an algorithm. Let me tell you a scenario.

I have a table of `templates`. These templates are updated through an api. Let say there are 13 templates. When i run the code these 13 templates will be gone to the database table `templates`. I have successfully done this even update the record if an id is already there.

So 2 cases i have managed to handle.

1-New record(insert that record)

2-Recorde Already there(So update that record).

Now the problem is lets suppose i deleted a template from the api. now there are 12 records which i am fetching from the api. How should i delete the one addition record present in my table.

One approach which is not a good one in my opinion is to delete all the records in the template data first and then run the query to insert the records. I need help in this regard.

I should do it in the `sql` side or the `php` side?

Comment: The same way you would delete any other record?

Comment: I believe I understand what you're asking. A potential solution could be adding a timestamp to each template entry. Then you can just say delete all records older than whatever timestamp you just added.

Comment: @RobertHarvey i have edited the question if it is uunclear and other thing is i cannot simply loop again and check the records and delete these records.

Comment: @AlexDeCamillo for the timestamp it is very difficult to mantain the timestamp with every record and then check the record against this timestamp.

Comment: @knowledge_seeker which is the difficult part? Here's the steps you can take: You should add a column for the timestamp, then whenever your PHP is going to insert the new records, have it get the current time and insert that with each record. After doing this, you can run a delete sql command with the condition that the time is older than that same timestamp variable you just created

Comment: @AlexDeCamillo actually i cannot add the timestamp to the database. or any kind of column as i am linking this to the CRM. I am not allowed to do this. other thing is timestamp is not a solution because it will update every record it is generating. My data is coming from api and there is not such thing as timestamp from the api.